# My code is working on port8080 but after deployment, I got 500 Server Error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud

**The problem I have encountered:**

I'm deploying my node.js web app at App Engine standard environment

Issue - My code is working on port8080 but after deployment, I got 500 Server Error

*****Displayed error message on browser*****

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

---

What I was expected to happen:

As code is working fine at port 8080 so I was expecting to see my app code running after app deployment same as it is running on port 8080

NOTE I have not received any !!!Critical !!!Alert or !!!Emergency in LOGS

**Error in Browser Console**
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

---

** ----- Other information ---- **

NOTE: I'm using node v12.20.0

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "ecomm12",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ecommerce training and services",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "start-server": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "R",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.9"
  }
}
```

is it ok to use 12.x.x package.json?
as I'm using nodemon is it ok to use "start": "nodemon app.js",?

Noting is there in Logs Explorer (!!!Critical !!!Alert or !!!Emergency) then how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to move nodemon from devDep to dependencies definition and deploy again. Let me know if it's better.

Comment: If moving nodemon to `dependencies` doesn't help, please add the error from [SDK logs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/tail) `gcloud app logs tail`